# Save Form submissions to google sheets

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-sheets

I am testing a simple form website that takes certain responses and does a typing speed test and stores the results to a google sheets link

here's the html code

`

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Volunteer Recruitment Form</title>
<style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
  
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      color: #333;
    }
  
    form {
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
  
    p {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
  
    input[type=text] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  
    input[type=submit] {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  
    input[type=submit]:hover {
      background-color: #45a049;
    }
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
<h1>Volunteer Recruitment Form</h1>

<img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" width="200" height="200">
<form onsubmit="return !!(saveFormResponses() & measureTypingSpeed());">
<p>1. Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
<p>2. Address: <input type="text" name="address"></p>
<p>3. Class: <input type="text" name="class"></p>
<p>4. Section: <input type="text" name="section"></p>
<p>5. Typing Speed Test:
<script>
    var sentences = [
      "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
      "She sells seashells by the seashore.",
      "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain.",
      "I saw Susie sitting in a shoe shine shop.",
      "How can a clam cram in a clean cream can?",
      "A proper copper coffee pot."
    ];
    
    var randomSentences = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      // Generate a random number between 0 and the length of the sentences array
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * sentences.length);
    
    
      randomSentences.push(sentences[randomIndex]);
    }
    
   
    document.write(randomSentences.join("<br>"));
</script>
<input type="text" name="typing_test"></p>

<script>
    function measureTypingSpeed() {
  
  var inputElement = document.querySelector("input[name=typing_test]");

  // Get the text of the sentences the user needs to type
  var sentences = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. She sells seashells by the seashore. The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain. I saw Susie sitting in a shoe shine shop. How can a clam cram in a clean cream can? A proper copper coffee pot.";

  
  var startTime = Date.now();
  var endTime = Date.now();
  while (inputElement.value != sentences) {
    endTime = Date.now();
  }

  
  var elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
  var words = sentences.split(" ").length;
  var typingSpeed = Math.round(words / (elapsedTime / 1000) * 60);

  
  alert("Your typing speed is: " + typingSpeed + " words per minute");
}

</script>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

`
and the code for the google sheets saving is

`

```
function saveFormResponses() {
  
  var formElement = document.querySelector("form");

  
  var formResponses = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < formElement.elements.length; i++) {
    var inputElement = formElement.elements[i];

    
    if (inputElement.type == "text") {
      formResponses[inputElement.name] = inputElement.value;
    }
  }

  
  const SPREADSHEET_URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zVvU0_VzrjmcOl33E4BOKhlsGt26cQQVnpV8R4AJvSw/edit?usp=sharing";

  
  const sheets = GoogleSheetsAPI.initialize();

  // Append the form responses to the bottom of the sheet
  sheets.append(SPREADSHEET_URL, formResponses);
}
```

`

Please help me solve the problem I am new to this and just learning through github hosting at the moment

I tried the given code but that doesnt seem to work

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Are you getting a specific error? Are you getting no errors, but it's not doing what you want it to? Is it something else? (Adding this info to your original post and future posts will probably help.)

Comment: well, im not getting errors, but its just not doing the part where when the form is submitted it makes a new entry on the google sheets file.